# Connection failed socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

I'm trying to create a program that connect with itself.
I trigger a thread client and a thread server and I create a socket to each thread. I use the same port.

When the thread client tries to connect to thread server, the connection fails. Why? I can't understanding. Help me!

The full code it's complicated, because it's big. But I'll generalize.

```
#define ADDR "127.0.0.1"

struct threadData{
    int portnum;
    int sockid;
    int lastID;
    unsigned int lastCheck;
};

// ----------- ----- Connection ------ ------------- //

void dieError(char *message, int socket){
    printf("%s\n", message);
    if(socket != 0)
        close(socket);
    exit(1);
}

int createSocket(int portnum, struct sockaddr_in* netw){
    int sockid;

    sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockid == -1)
        dieError("socket() failed", sockid);

    struct in_addr addrr;
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, ADDR, &addrr) < 1)
        dieError("pton() failed", sockid);

    netw->sin_family = AF_INET;
    netw->sin_port = htons(portnum);
    netw->sin_addr = addrr;

    return sockid;
}

void listenSocket(struct threadData* thd, struct sockaddr_in* netw){

    if(bind(thd->sockid, (struct sockaddr *) netw, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
        dieError("bind() failed", thd->sockid);

    if(listen(thd->sockid, 0) == -1)
        dieError("listen() failed", thd->sockid);
}

int acceptConnection(int sockid, struct sockaddr* addrr){
    socklen_t cLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    int cSocket = accept(sockid, addrr, &cLen);

    if(cSocket == -1)
        dieError("accept() failed", sockid);

    return cSocket;
}

int createConnection(int portnum, struct sockaddr_in* netw){
    int sockid = createSocket(portnum, netw);

    fcntl(sockid, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

    if(connect(sockid, (struct sockaddr *) netw, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
        dieError("connect() failed", sockid);

    return sockid;
}

// ----------- ----- ---------- ------ ------------- //

//Receptor thread
void * verifyPort(void * param){
    struct threadData* thd = param;
    int cSocket;
    struct sockaddr addrr;
    struct sockaddr_in* netw = (struct sockaddr_in*) malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

    thd->sockid = createSocket(thd->portnum, netw);
    listenSocket(thd, netw);
    cSocket = acceptConnection(thd->sockid, &addrr);
}

//Sender thread
void verifyKeyboard(int portnum){
    int sockid;
    struct sockaddr_in* netw = (struct sockaddr_in*) malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sockid = createConnection(portnum, netw);
}

// ----------- ---- -------- ------- ------------- //

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    pthread_t tid;
    struct threadData* thd;
    thd = (struct threadData*) malloc(sizeof(struct threadData));

    thd->portnum = atoi(argv[1]);
    thd->lastID = -1;
    thd->lastCheck = 0;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, verifyPort, thd);

    verifyKeyboard(atoi(argv[1]));

    free(thd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It may be worth printing error messages with [`strerror(errno)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) (`strerror` is defined in `<string.h>` and `errno` is defined in `<errno.h>`)

Comment: Probably the full code would help.

Comment: Fails how? Fails to connect? Times out? Does nothing? Gets reset?

Comment: This looks suspicious:  `if(listen(thd->sockid, 0) == -1)`  A backlog queue of pending connections with a max length of zero?

Comment: Sigh. Doesn't connect how? Connection refused? Connection timed out? Host unreachable? No route to host? Bad argument? Segmentation violation? You were asked to provide an error code or error message. So provide it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That will be adjusted upwards to the platform minimum.

Comment: Even if everything is ok with the setup, it may be just a race condition between connect() and listen(), where the former is called to early. Sleep for a second before connecting to be sure that socket is ready.

Comment: I solved the problem. It was because of this `fcntl(sockid, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`

Comment: Please delete this useless question. There is no clear problem statement nor any explanation of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you are passing the wrong size of the address structure to `connect()` in the client thread. This:

```
if (connect(sockid, addrr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1)
```

Should probably be:

```
if (connect(sockid, addrr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1)
```

To indicate that you are passing an internet address to `connect()`. `sizeof(struct sockaddr)` is clearly wrong, since that's just the generic structure type.

It's hard to pinpoint other problems without more code.

Comment: I fixed the code I wrote wrong but the size of the address structure to connect() is strcut sockaddr.
```
int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```
[http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/connect.2.html)

Comment: @Jeff sockaddr is an umbrella type over various address family-specific structs. It's size may be less than or more than actual address struct like sockaddr_in, otherwise addrlen would not be needed at all.

Comment: @Jeff: Filipe is right, you need to pass `connect()` the size of the actual socket address structure that you passed, in this case `sizeof *netw`.  Consider that if you always had to pass it `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`, why would you need to pass it at all?

Comment: I solved the problem. It was because of this `fcntl(sockid, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`